# Should I add yeast when bottling an IPA after sitting in secondary for 1.5 months

Tags: fermentation, yeast, bottling, secondary-fermentation, priming

I'm VERY new to homebrewing. This is my first 5gal batch. I moved from primary to secondary after 1-2 weeks. I then (due to life, work, forgetting to order bottles) have left the beer in the secondary for 1.5 months. It is an IPA. I'm wondering if I should pitch additional yeast when I bottle or is there enough active yeast to carbonate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  There *should* be enough yeast still present to carbonate your bottles.  If you want to be sure, it wouldn't be wrong just to add about 1 gram of fresh yeast before bottling.  You don't need a whole pack, just a tiny amount.  But this is optional.  I'll bet if you don't add any more yeast it will still carbonate just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I try doing it without and see what happens. Now that I have the bottles I have no excuse next time!